# How to get text of <label> tag with webdriver librairy of python

Tags: python, webdriver

I am working with the following html structure :

```html
<table id="campaignSPTree_id">
  <tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="r1r0c0">
        <a>
          <span>
                <label class="hidden-label">Tree level 1, 1 of 25. </label>
              </span>
        </a </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to retrieve the text of the `<label>` tag. I have tried this code but it doesn't work :

```
    maxPP = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='campaignSPTree_id']/tbody/tr[2]/td/a/span/label").get_attribute("class").text
```

I don't understand why I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

Could you, please, help me to get this famous text ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think `browser.find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list and you cant use `get_attribute` for lists. Thats why you get that error.

Comment: And why does it work with the code: find_element_by_id () ?

Comment: @ChristopheC. Because an ID can just be used once on a website and a class as often as you want.

Comment: Just use find_element_by_id... Didnt you say it worked with it?

Comment: But I don't have id in my <label> tag ?

Comment: Can you maybe show the code? This would help me to help you.

Comment: @ChristopheC. and by the way its not a lable. It is a table I just realised xD

Comment: I don't have an id in the <label> tag. I just have an id in the <td> tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me but without really understanding why :

```
maxPP = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@id='r1r0c0']/a/span/label")[0].get_attribute("innerHTML")
```